# Sending a Terminate (Ctrl+C) Command in Node.js SSH2

Tags: node.js, ssh

I am using Node.js SSH2 module(https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2).  myScript.py executes continuously.  How can I stop it while keeping the SSH connection alive?

```
var Connection = require('ssh2');
var c = new Connection();
c.on('ready', function() {
  c.exec('python myScript.py', function(err, stream) {
    if (err) throw err;
    stream.on('data', function(data, extended) {
      //this callback gets called multiple times as the script writes to stdout
      console.log((extended === 'stderr' ? 'STDERR: ' : 'STDOUT: ') + data);
      allData+=data;
    });
  });
});
c.connect({
  host: xxx.xxx.x.xx,
  port: 22,
  username: 'user',
  password: 'pass'
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We got the same problem in our research group and our solution is to fetch the process ID of the remote process when first executing the command and then kill it when needed.

*It seems python processes are continuing to live detached in the background if you only use the `kill [pid]` command, therefore we used the `pkill -g [pid]` command in our solution below. This might be different or the same in other cases. But I guess it's good to know that you shoud try both cases if one doesn't work for you.*

This is our (simplified) solution. Of course it does not make sense to kill every exec command after 5 seconds... but you will get the idea (and a safe `pid/conn` scope for reuse):

```
var Connection = require('ssh2');
var c = new Connection();

function killProcess(conn, pid) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('Killing PID ' + pid);
        conn.exec('pkill -g ' + pid, function(){});
    }, 5000);
}

c.on('ready', function() {
    // echo $$; gives you the PID, we prepend it with the string
    // "EXEC PID: " to later on know for sure which line we grab as PID
    c.exec('echo "EXEC PID: $$";python myScript.py', function(err, stream) {
        if(err) throw err;
        stream.on('data', function(buffer) {
            var line = '' + buffer; // unbeautiful ;)
            console.log(line);
            if(line.substr(0, 10) === 'EXEC PID: ') {
                killProcess(c, line.substr(10));
            }
        }).on('end', function() {
            console.log('exec killed');
        });
    });
});
c.connect({
  host: xxx.xxx.x.xx,
  port: 22,
  username: 'user',
  password: 'pass'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that not all SSH servers support the packet sent by signal(), this includes OpenSSH as of this writing.

Fortunately for SIGINT, you can usually get the expected behavior by instead writing '\x03' to the stream.

Comment: stream.write('\x03'); does not do anything and does not raise errors.  the same goes for c.exec('\x03'.......

Comment: Well you can always end the stream with `stream.end();`, that should always kill the process on the remote end.

Comment: After I call stream.end(); should I call c.exec('python myScript.py', function(err, stream) {... to restart the script?

Comment: Yes, that should work fine if you need to restart it.

Comment: Would making stream a global variable be a good idea?  I need to kill it outside of the Connection object.

Comment: I suppose you could if you really needed to do that. I would make sure to unset the variable after calling .end() though to prevent calling .end() multiple times on the same stream.

Comment: stream.end() worked for me.  I guess stackoverflow does not allow accepting comments, only answers...

Comment: For me neither `stream.signal('INT')` nor `stream.write('\x03')` nor `stream.end()` cause the stream to stop emitting output on STDOUT and exit.  Any potential other ways?